# Proving entire function is identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, entire-functions

i am given an entire function $f$, and i know that 
$$\lvert f(z)\rvert\leq\sqrt{\lvert z\rvert}\sqrt{\lvert z-1\rvert}$$
for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. How do i go about proving that $f$ is identically zero?

I had the following idea, clearly $f(0)=0$, and thus if we can prove $f$ is constant, then it is identically zero. To prove it is constant i initially thought i would be able to use liouvilles theorem, however i am unable to rewrite it to be bounded.

(This is not homework, it is a question from a previous exam)

Comment: The Cauchy estimates show that $f$ must be a polynomial of small degree. How many zeros of $f$ do you know immediately?

Comment: We know of two zeroes, and i am fairly sure that i would be able to bound $g(z)$ for $f(z)=z(z-1)g(z)$

Comment: You can do much better. What is the best bound for the degree that you can immediately see from the growth condition?

Comment: Ah! Linear! beacuse its the product of two square roots right?

Comment: Correct. And a polynomial of degree $\leqslant 1$ having two roots …

Comment: Ah, thats impossible, so by contradiction $f$ has to be identically zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(0) = f(1) = 0$ so that
$$
  f(z) = z(z-1)g(z)
$$
with an entire function $g$. Then
$$
|g(z)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lvert z\rvert}\sqrt{\lvert z-1\rvert}}
$$
for $z \to \infty$, so that $g$ is bounded, therefore (Liouville!) constant, and consequently identically zero.

Comment: How do you go from $|g(z)|$ bounded to $|f(z)|$bounded when $z(z-1)$ is not? Am i correct that its coming from the fact that $|g(z)|\rightarrow0$ for $z\rightarrow\infty$ and thus g has to be $0$ from the maximum modulus principle?

Comment: @kumalka: Liouville is applied to $g$, not to $f$. Then $g=0$ implies $f=0$.

Comment: Ah, now i'm following, i saw that $g$ was a constant, but i was not sure how we made sure it was zero, but that comes from $z\rightarrow\infty$ as far as i have understood.